# Why does npm install packages locally?

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies

This is more of a design question, and might not belong here ( do let me know ). As far as I understand most of the languages install their dependencies in a common space ( /usr/local/ ... ) or use some project / environment specific isolation ( different folders to hold different versions ). What was the thought process of npm creators to install dependencies locally? What pros and cons might have been considered ? How has this decision affected the current landscape?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, you still get "local" installation using other build systems. The global usages of linked libraries is also done but it has proven time and time again to be exceptionally unreliable, hence why a build artefact would *ideally* include everything it needs as opposed to grasping for random DLLs or other global resources that might or might not be there and might or might not have the correct version, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What was the thought process of npm creators to install dependencies locally?

Like you sad `different folders to hold different versions`.

> What pros and cons might have been considered?

PRO:

- Easy dependency isolation when for multiple projects on the same machine.

  If you take `pip` (for Python) you will need to set up a
  `virtual-env` if you like to manage multiple projects on the same
  host. The `virtual-env` abstract the environment variables to achieve
  what npm dose with folders.

CON:

- The same version dependencies will not be shared between projects.
- Env management - Sometime dev-dependencies (tooling) will find there way to the normal dependencies if you not careful.

> How has this decision affected the current landscape?

Not that match I would say. Now days using `docker` creating an isolation environment is more essayer the ever. This means that in production a docker container is isolated.

Regarding dev environment more and more developers are moving to docker [`dev-container`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers) which makes the isolation issue obsolete.